# how to enable ldap over ssl in jndi

Tags: ssl, ldap, solaris, jndi

I have a sun LDAP server on a solaris machine, and my web application can connect to the LDAP over 389 port. Now I want to connect to LDAP over SSL using 636 port. In my LDAP server I have installed the certificate. Now I have exported the certificate using a key from the LDAP server so that I can use this certificate with my web application. On the same machine my glassfish server is also installed. I copied the certificate in the /usr/java/jre/lib/security/ folder. Now in my web application I used this code to connect to the LDAP over sll but it is unable to connect to the LDAP.

```
 Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
 ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
 ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://ldapserver:636");
 ht.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "EXTERNAL");
 // ht.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/usr/java/jre/lib/security/cert");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",certpass);
 ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,binddn);
 // Specify SSL
 ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
 ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,bindpass);
```

What am I doing wrong? Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL/TLS certificate you installed on your LDAP server is a self-signed one or its signer certificate doesn't exist in your JVM's `lib/security/cacerts` truststore, you need to import the certificate into a truststore and specify where that truststore is by setting the System properties `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`. You seem to have already imported the certificate into a JKS file (assuming it is JKS format). You need to point `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to that file and specify its password so JVM can access to it.